# Significance of Mutual Information with Conditional Group

Tags: python, numpy, math, scikit-learn

I have three features, A, B and C. 
I want to know whether A and B are dependent given C. I can only find chi-squared implementation of A and B, but not given C.
Is there a ready library that does this (preferably Python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ranmoshe/Inference - it does exactly what you want, including a correct calculation of the degrees of freedom of A|C, B|C.